# PostgreSQL - regexp_replace sobre SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy trabajando con **PostgreSQL** y no logro realizar una consulta de reemplazo mediante **REGEXP_REPLACE**. Lo que necesito es que la columna pase de como se ve del lado izquierdo a lo que figura en el lado derecho:

```
-------------             -------------
-- original               -- modificado
-------------             -------------
142/16                    142
145/16                    145
146/16                    146
147/16                    147
16/F/2016                 16
213/G/2016                213
233-M-2015                233
24/G/2016                 24
24/S/2016                 24
25/L/2016                 25
269/S/2016                269
28/S/2016                 28
```

Necesito que solo se mantenga *el valor antes de* '/' o '-'.

He intentado cosas como:

```
SELECT
  columna                                    AS original,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(columna, '/(\w)*(\d)*', '') AS modificado
FROM tabla;

SELECT
  columna                                             AS original,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(columna, '^/[a-zA-Y0-9 ]', '', 'gi') AS modificado
FROM tabla;

SELECT
  columna                                            AS original,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(columna, '(/[\d*+])(\w)', '', 'gi') AS modificado
FROM tabla;
```

...pero ninguna me arroja lo que necesito.

Alguien que pueda orientarme o darme una mano. Gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 1):

Luego de batallar un buen rato con expresiones regulares, encontré la solución que por lo menos hasta el momento me resulta. No se si es la mas optima pero la dejo a continuación:

```
SELECT
  columna                                                                  AS original,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(columna, '((/|-)+[[:alpha:]]*)+([[:digit:]]*)', '', 'gi') AS modificado
FROM tabla;
```

Si alguno tiene una mejor forma, favor postearlo.